# How to push multiple values to a map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have to push multiple values to a map and below what i tried:

I have an ename = 'Test1' and i have to retrieve all his details.so i did query to get the details from the empname and the result is below:

```
   String ename='Test1'
   Map<String, Map<String, Object>> empData = new HashMap<String, 
   HashMap<String, Object>>()

   ​def empDetails=[[job:'Dev',exp:2],[job:'QA',exp:4]]
   Map<String, Object> empColl = new HashMap<String, Object>() 
   empDetails.eachWithIndex{itr,index->  //looping through empDetails   
         empColl.put("job",itr.job);  
         empColl.put("exp",itr.exp); 
   }

  empData.put(ename,empColl);
  println empData;​  //I see only one value in the map
```

But i want the expected output to be:

```
  [Test1:[[job:'Dev',exp:2][job:QA, exp:4]]].
```

Comment: you have `Map<String,Map>` but as expected result  you want `Map<String, List<Map>>`

Comment: @daggett - I modified as per your suggestion but the results looks same:Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> empData = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>()

Comment: ok. but you have to change your code, not only type definition...

Comment: btw `empData = [ename: empDetails]` builds desired result

Comment: @daggett - empData = [ename: empDetails] i dont see the ename i.e 'Test1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String ename='Test1'
def empDetails=[[job:'Dev',exp:2],[job:'QA',exp:4]]
def empData = ["$ename": empDetails]
```

returns

```
[Test1:[[job:Dev, exp:2], [job:QA, exp:4]]]
```

Comment: `def empData = [(ename): empDetails]` is better as it avoids using a templated string as a key